# Ignore non entity property when save projection changes in WCF Data Services

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

To reduce amount of data coming from WCF Data Services I use a projection technique.

Linq query looked like:

```
...
    _ctx.Files.Select(x => new FileProjection() { Id=x.Id, Name = x.Name });
...

[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class FileProjection : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
        }
    }

    public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

FileProjection class has an additional property that doesn't exist in File entity model.

It works fine while getting the data. But If I tried to update Name I got an exception inside SaveChanges:

> Additional information: The property 'MyCustomProperty' does not exist
>   on type 'DataAccessLayer.Context.File'. Make sure to only use property
>   names that are defined by the type.

Is there a way to ignore MyCustomProperty during SaveChanges?

Or XXXProjection class shouldn't have any custom public properties?

The client is Silverlight app, WCF Data Services v5.0.1, oData v3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the only way to do this is to make the property internal or private. All public properties will be serialized and the server will then fail if it doesn't recognize it.

Or you can use a workaround by Phani: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/12/11/customizing-serialization-of-entities-in-the-ado-net-data-services-client-library.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

This issue with the previous workarounds (using an event handler for the `DataServiceContext.WritingEntity` event) is that it only worked on Atom - it doesn't work on JSON.

New versions of the WCF Data Services Client and OData Client now support some pipeline event interception, which works for both JSON and ATOM.  More info here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2013/07/26/using-the-new-client-hooks-in-wcf-data-services-client.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If private or internal isn't going to work for you as in my case you can simply use methods instead.

```
public string GetName()
public void SetName(string value)
```

These methods will ignore serialization and you can maintain state across class libraries.